# How to write a spring data jpa query method with a negated enum constant?

Tags: enums, spring-data-jpa

I'd like to query a database using a Spring Data JPA query method and retrieve the records which do not have a certain enum value. What's working is

```
findBySuggestionNot(Suggestion suggestion, Pageable pageable);
```

and then I hand in e.g. `Suggestion.rejected`.

What I want is

```
findBySuggestionNotRejected(Pageable pageable);
```

But this results in an error because "NotRejected" is not a property of Suggestion. Any pointers?

Comment: i dont think  you can - unless you use a @Query

Answer (score 0):

Using full-qualified name instand of XENUM.XXX, eg:

```
where a.status= com.foo.bar.Status.ACTIVED
```

And Be Careful, your enum should be uppercase ranther then lowercase ,camel case, otherwise the exception like "invalid path com.foo.bar.Status.ACTIVED ..." would be throw by spring. I am using Spring Boot 2.1.1.RELEASE